# OSX 10.7 $(window).width() returning the wrong value

Tags: javascript, html, css, macos, osx-lion

I can't be the first to notice this but ever since 10.7 came out and they implemented the new style of scrollbars $(window).width() and $(window).height() no longer correctly return the size of the browser windows viewport....

Lets say you want to set a div the size of the browser window on load eh...

```
// load jquery //
    
<div id="bob">
</div>
    
    <script>
      $('#bob').width($(window).width()).height($(window).height());
    </script>
```

and what ends up happening is something like this
[image]

To this I ask **WTF**?

*here is an example of the issue*

http://lab.aerotwist.com/webgl/a3/vertex-manipulation/

Comment: Is this just under Safari, or do other browsers exhibit this behavior in Lion as well?

Comment: every browser I have tested the result is the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do the elements containing `#bob` have margin or padding? If they do, that could be adding more space beyond the width and height of `#bob`, forcing scrollbars to appear.

If that's the problem, you could fix that by adding CSS like this:

```
html, body, #bob {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: any ideas on this link.. http://lab.aerotwist.com/webgl/a3/vertex-manipulation/ ?

Comment: @samccone: Add `display: block;` to the `canvas`.

Comment: ah! so so so smart .. i feel dumb now :\